# How to ensure that a user in Rails can update/insert/delete only his/her record in a database

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, entitlements

Sorry if this is an elementary question but I've just started to consider whether I've been doing this correctly all along.  Usually when a user tries to update the database, I simply use his/her username as the key in a user table and then base all operations on that.  However I just realized that a crafty user MIGHT be able to submit a query using another username name thus circumventing this weak form of enforcing entitlements.  So my question really is how do I prevent a user from potentially submitting a destructive action against a database under a different userid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the current user's ID in the session, which isn't easily manipulated.

I usually refer to the objects through a relation on a User object:

```
    current_user.fragile_records.find(params[:id]).destroy
```

It's a readable and simple way of doing an ownership test.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html is a surprisingly good read on the subject.

There are plenty of readymade solutions for [maintaining user identity (authentication)](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authentication) and [ensuring user has clearance for an action (authorization)](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization) in Rails.